# Angular injector moduler error persists. Why?

Tags: angularjs

I've fiddled around with my project trying to refactor it (all my controllers and config were in a single file and the project is big) using modules for the controllers, and at some point i did something wrong, of course. Problem is, now i just cant get rid of this error, even after i re downloaded angular and tried different versions as well. The only way i get rid of it is if i don't include angular at all. WHY?!?!?!?!

EDIT: now it all seems in order and yet the problem persists. why? or does angular ignore the actual order in some way and it takes everything randomly?

code for filling:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Perfect Memorials Reports">
        <meta name="author" content="Perfect Memorials">

        <title>Perfect Memorials Reports</title>
        {{ HTML::style('/resources/styles/preloader.css') }}
        {{ HTML::style('/resources/styles/bootstrap.css') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/jquery.min.js') }}

        <!-- JQuery UI -->
        {{ HTML::style('/resources/plugins/jqueryui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/plugins/jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/bootstrap.min.js') }}

        <!-- Noty plugin -->
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/plugins/noty/jquery.noty.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/plugins/noty/layouts/top.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/plugins/noty/themes/default.js') }}        

        <!-- JQuery UI touch enanle -->
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js') }}

        <!-- Datepicker -->
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}  

        <!-- Chosen Plugin --> 
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/chosen.jquery.js') }}      

        <!-- Angular -->
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/angular/angular.min.js') }}
        {{ HTML::script('/resources/javascript/angular/angular-route.min.js') }} 

        {{ HTML::script('/src/Foundation/Application.js') }}


        @yield('head')

        {{ HTML::style('/resources/fonts/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}
        {{ HTML::style('/resources/styles/chosen.css') }}
        {{ HTML::style('/resources/styles/style.css') }}

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">

        <base href="/">
    </head>

    <body ng-app="ReporterApplication" ng-controller="BootstrapController as bootstrap">

    </body>
</html>
```

the Application.js file's code:

```
/**
 * Angular application main module
 * 
 * @author Jorj Daniel <jorj_daniel@yahoo.com>
 */

var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', 
['ngRoute', 'ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
        $routeProvider
      .when('/packing/scan.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
        controller: 'PackingScanController'
      })

      .when('/packing/stats.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/stats.html',
        controller: 'PackingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/packing/error.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/error.html',
        controller: 'PackingErrorController'
      })

      .when('/packing/shipping-statistics.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/shipping-statistics.html',
        controller: 'ShippingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/tracking/orders.html', {
        templateUrl: 'tracking/orders.html',
        controller: 'OrdersTrackerController'
      })

      .when('/tracking/orders-statistics.html', {
        templateUrl: 'tracking/orders-statistics.html',
        controller: 'TrackingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/jewelry-room.html', {
        templateUrl: 'jewelry-room.html',
        controller: 'JewelryRoomController'
      })

      .when('/administration/jobs', {
        templateUrl: 'administration/jobs',
        controller: 'AdministrationJobsController'
      });

 }]);
```

EDIT 2: included everything. all the angular js code is currently in the bootstrap file

EDIT 3: tried rewriting from scratch, error still up

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: lo and behold http://puu.sh/iuOUA/d36726f273.png

Comment: Are you telling your website to use your ng-app somewhere? Could you show us the html code where you define your app? And the bit where you inject your controller module in your main app?

Comment: Instead of creating a new question, you could have asked for help on the matter in a comment on my answer on your previous question though..

Comment: i edited it. this is all i need for the error to pop up

Comment: Could you remove the ng-app="ReporterApplication" from the <html> tag and create a <body> tag and place the ng-app in there?

Comment: Basicly you are telling your website it is an ng-app before you included the appropriate libraries

Comment: allright, that "solved" it i guess. it seems angular thinks that i have injected something if i try to give ng app a name (without declaring it, i think). it's pretty confusing

Comment: No the reason was that you try to use a library before you even include that library. If you place the ng-app="ReporterApplication" in your <body> tag, it will try to use the library after you included it.

Comment: And if my answers to both question helped you fix the problem, please be as kind as to mark them as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: of course, as soon as i will have this sorted out, i will

Comment: The naming of your files doesn't really make clear what's what btw, thus making it hard to say whether you have the right order of including.. And I would put the controller on a <div> inside the body tag instead of on the body tag itself, but I'm not sure if that causes any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to convert my comments to an answer, Remove the ng-app="ReporterApp" from your html tag, and place it in your body tag.

It would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- all script includes here -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="ReporterApplication">
    </body>
</html>
```

This way instead of trying to use the library before you even included it, you use the library after including it. If you applied the structure of the modules and injecting the dependencies as I answered in your previous question, everything should work fine.

**Update**

Ah I see the problem. You are using the interpolateprovider in your module definition, while you should put this in your .config(). While defining a module you only inject dependencies. You can't inject the interpolateProvider that way.

It should look like this I guess:

```
var Application = angular.module('ReporterApplication', 
['ngRoute', 'ui.select', 'ngSanitize']);

Application.config(['$routeProvider', '$interpolateProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
        $routeProvider
      .when('/packing/scan.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/scan.html',
        controller: 'PackingScanController'
      })

      .when('/packing/stats.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/stats.html',
        controller: 'PackingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/packing/error.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/error.html',
        controller: 'PackingErrorController'
      })

      .when('/packing/shipping-statistics.html', {
        templateUrl: 'packing/shipping-statistics.html',
        controller: 'ShippingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/tracking/orders.html', {
        templateUrl: 'tracking/orders.html',
        controller: 'OrdersTrackerController'
      })

      .when('/tracking/orders-statistics.html', {
        templateUrl: 'tracking/orders-statistics.html',
        controller: 'TrackingStatisticsController'
      })

      .when('/jewelry-room.html', {
        templateUrl: 'jewelry-room.html',
        controller: 'JewelryRoomController'
      })

      .when('/administration/jobs', {
        templateUrl: 'administration/jobs',
        controller: 'AdministrationJobsController'
      });

 }]);
```

Comment: i still haven't quite sorted this all out but i greatly appreciate your support, so i marked your answers. also do you know where i could learn a bit more about structure so i can better get the hang of it all? it's pretty confusing and i really don't understand how this all works

Comment: Structure is a matter of preferences I guess, Usually you follow a structure the company you work at allready uses, then you get used to that and apply that structure to all of your own work.. You could have a look at this post: http://angularjs.blogspot.nl/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html

Comment: If the error still persists, but looks different now, feel free to ask